# scrolling window using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am writing a script for linkedin using selenium python and facing a issue. I want to scroll window of dialog but my script start scrolling window which is at the back.

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login?goback=&trk=hb_signin')
driver.find_element_by_name('session_key').send_keys(email)
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_id('session_password-login').send_keys(password,Keys.RETURN) 
time.sleep(7)
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/in/rickblack/skills/(ACoAAAC4aQcBoD2OHCmDN1Fe7n2dMtoVYkWTz4o,27)/')
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
for o in range(0,5):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try to use below code to define last person in a list and scroll down to it:

```
the_last_in_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="pv-endorsement-entity__detail  pl3')[-1]
the_last_in_list.location_once_scrolled_into_view
```

P.S. You might need to do this couple times as list of persons initially is not complete: you need to scroll down to trigger `XHR` to add (load) more persons...

P.P.S. Note, that `driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])` makes nothing as there is no new browser windows opened, but just modal window in the same browser window

Comment: Thanks for your help