# How to scroll down an element on page

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to scrape names of companies from https://justjoin.it/, however my **scraper** has a problem with page scrolling. I usually use the following method to scroll down page:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, x)")
```

Unfortunately, on this page execute_script method doesn't work.

I tried also to manipulate the element with table od names by send_keys method, but my script raises error:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div')
elem.send_keys(Keys.END)



selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

Does anyone have an idea how to handle with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scrolling window using selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42332706/scrolling-window-using-selenium-python)

Comment: @12944qwerty No, it does not answer the question.

Comment: @vitaliis ohh, oops. I misread the error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. The page is not sensitive to scrolling the page until you click on the element with the list of jobs offers.

Comment: OK, so why not first click on the element with the list of jobs offers and then scroll to the element you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote, you first have to click on the element with the list of jobs offers and after that scroll to the desired element.
The scrolling will work fine in this case

Comment: So i tried to apply such line of code:
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div').click()
but when i run script, driver opens one of the job offer that is seen on the list.

Comment: Try clicking some other element so it will make the page active but will not open any link. I guess there are a lot of options to do so.